# Passing arguments from bash script to dql script

Tags: bash, shell, documentum

I want to write a script that enables a user to change a custom attribute of a business object.

I have written a bash-script that calls my dql script and passes one argument.

My dql-script looks like this:

```
UPDATE my_business_object OBJECT SET my_custom_attribute='my_custom_value' WHERE r_object_id='?'
go
```

My bash-script looks like this:

```
set /p delBuild=Please enter object-id: 
CALL C:\...path_to_idql\idql.exe connection_details -RC:\...path_to_dql_script\my_script.dql %1

PAUSE
```

This approach doesen't work. It seems like the parameter passing doesn't work. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: My assumption is that you are trying to reference a command-line variable with %1.  The first command-line variable would actually be $1.  Let me know if this assumption is wrong.

Comment: That is not a bash script. It looks more like a DOS script.

Comment: @Pascal Try enclose %1 into double quotes, like `"%1"`